# Typeahead Bootstrap does not work in remote

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

I have the following problem. Using Bootstrap Typeahead in a field on a form. When i run it on localhost it works perfect, but when i run it from another PC in network does not work. What can be happening?

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$("#typeahead").typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                process(data);
            }
        });
    }
});});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])) { 

require_once('conexion.php'); 

$query = $_POST['query']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab_medicinas_2 WHERE descripcion LIKE '%".$query."%'"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
{ 
    $return[] = $fila['descripcion']." (".$fila['um'].")"; 
} 

echo json_encode($return); }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tab4" class="tab-content-1">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td width="28%">Denominaci&oacute;n seg&uacute;n DCI, especificaciones t&eacute;cnicas, unidad de manejo</td>
        <td width="24%">Dosis</td>
        <td width="24%">Duraci&oacute;n del tratamiento</td>
        <td width="8%">Cant. Req.</td>
        <td width="16%">Indicaci&oacute;n Espec&iacute;fica</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="28%">
            <input name="descripcion" class="span4" id="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" />
        </td>
        <td width="24%">
            <input name="dosis" class="span3" id="dosis" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td width="24%">
            <input name="duracion" class="span3" id="duracion" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td width="8%">
            <input name="cantidad" class="span1" id="cantidad" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td width="16%">
            <input name="indicacion" class="span2" id="indicacion" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```